# Como aplicar estilo CSS em um botão ao clicar em outro (Invertendo os estilos)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

Olá,

Tenho dois botões, preciso aplicar o estilo de um ao clicar em outro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este são os estados iniciais, porém ao clicar em **"Select your product"** deve aplicar o estilo do botão **"Details"** e neste mesmo click o botão **"Details"** recebe o estilo do botão **"Select your product"**.

Em resumo eles invertem de cores, recebendo um o estilo do outro.

**Algumas observações:**

Só posso usar CSS, HTML e JavaScript.

Em cada botão já existe um evento onClick que chama uma Div com conteúdo especifico.

Tentei algo assim, mas não deu certo, acredito ser a lógica que está errada.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-btn">
  <button onClick="show('Details')" class="security-btn__details">Details</button>
  <button onClick="show('Product')" class="security-btn__product">Select your product</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.security-btn__details {
  background-color: #001428;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 18rem;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-right: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.security-btn__details:focus {
  background-color: #1e2e40;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 60%;
  width: 18rem;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00FFEE;
}
.security-btn__product {
  background-color: #1e2e40;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 60%;
  width: 18rem;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00FFEE;
}
.security-btn__product:focus {
  background-color: #001428;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 18rem;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-right: 1px solid #00FFEE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let myButton = document.querySelectorAll('security-btn__details');

myButton.forEach(function(key){
    key.addEventListener('click', function(){
        removeStyles();
        this.setAttribute('class', '.security-btn__product:focus');
    });
})

function removeStyles(){
    for(let i = 0;i < myButton.length;i++){
        document.querySelectorAll('security-btn__details')[i].removeAttribute('class');
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem alguns erros de sintaxe e precisa entender melhor a estrutura da construção e conversação entre elementos.

1. O método "querySelectorAll" não precisa ser usado nesse caso. Basta usar "querySelector".
2. A captação dos elementos não deve estar funcionando pois você esqueceu o "." que faz menção a uma classe. A sintaxe é:

   document.querySelector(".security-btn__product")

Note que tem um ponto antes do nome da classe...

3. Não existe fazer um "forEach" sendo que o "myButton" só tem um elemento
   no array

O ideal é usar "eventListeners" ao invés de funções que sujam o HTML como atributos "onClick"

```
buttonDetails = document.querySelector(".security-btn__details")
buttonProduct = document.querySelector(".security-btn__product")

buttonDetails.addEventListener("click", () => {
 buttonProduct.style.backgroundColor = "red"
 buttonDetails.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
})

buttonProduct.addEventListener("click", () => {
 buttonProduct.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
 buttonDetails.style.backgroundColor = "red"
})
```

Perceba que o evento de click vai ser executado agindo somente na alternação das cores dos background... O css não precisa ser mexido, pois o javascript é executado posteriormente se o seu arquivo .js estiver no fim da página como indicam as recomendações. Abraço!

Caso essa resposta ajude você, aceite para a resolução do seu problema